# diff wc help on unix

Tags: unix, diff

I compared two files file1 and file2 using `diff -y`. When I performed `wc -l` on the diff file I got a value of 66000. Previously I had concatenated the same file1 and file2 for something else and had performed `wc -l` on it. I got about 84000 lines as the count.

Shouldn't the number of lines be the same when I do a `wc -l` on both the diff file and the concatenated file? Am I missing something in the diff file?

I also counted how many contents are different between the two files , how many are same and how many are seen present in only one vs the other and then summed them up and they are coming up to be a total of 66000.

When I concatenated I did

```
sort | uniq | wc -l
```

When I diffed it I just did a

```
wc -l
```

However the files were already `sort`ed and `uniq`ed files that were diffed. Can't figure out what I missed!

Comment: I now see your problem: You're wondering about the number of lines in a _sorted_ and _uniqued_ concatenation. Wouldn't have been bad to state your question more clearly. I'm withdrawing my answer. WRT to your question: I have to assume either a whitespace problem (addition whitespace in one of the files) or a mistake on your part. Can't know.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the way **`diff -y`** displays "changed" and "moved" lines, there may be no relationship between the number of lines **`diff -y`** displays, and the number of lines displayed by combining the original files and filtering through sort and uniq(ue) as you have described.

Here we have 2 sorted files, with 20 and 19 lines. Sort+uniq of the 2 files together displays 32 lines, but diff displays only 20 lines:

```
             | file1+2 |
             | sort    |  diff -y -W 12
file1| file2 | uniq    |  file1 file2
-----|-------|---------|---------------
act     act     act       act     act
all     all     all       all     all
and     and     and       and     and
bar     can     bar       bar  |  can
boy     car     boy       boy  |  car
but     cat     but       but  |  cat
dad     dad     can       dad     dad
day     eat     car       day  |  eat
did     eel     cat       did  |  eel
dip     egg     dad       dip  |  egg
far     get     day       far  |  get
fir     gum     did       fir  |  gum
for     gym     dip       for  |  gym
hat     ill     eat       hat  |  ill
him     ink     eel       him  |  ink
hip     its     egg       hip  |  its
how     zap     far       how  <
zap     zip     fir       zap     zap
zip     zoo     for       zip     zip
zoo             get       zoo     zoo
                gum
                gym
                hat
                him
                hip
                how
                ill
                ink
                its
                zap
                zip
                zoo
-----|-------|---------|---------------
20   |  19   |  32     |  20
```

Here we have 2 sorted files, with 19 lines each. Sort+uniq of the 2 files together displays 31 lines, and diff also displays 31 lines:

```
             | file1+2 |
             | sort    |  diff -y -W 12
file1| file2 | uniq    |  file1 file2
-----|-------|---------|---------------
act     act     act       act     act
all     all     all       all     all
and     and     and       and     and
fad     bar     bar            >  bar
far     boy     boy            >  boy
fir     but     but            >  but
for     can     can            >  can
get     car     car            >  car
gum     cat     cat            >  cat
gym     dad     dad            >  dad
hat     day     day            >  day
him     did     did            >  did
hip     eat     eat            >  eat
ill     eel     eel            >  eel
ink     egg     egg            >  egg
its     fad     fad       fad     fad
zap     zap     far       far  <
zip     zip     fir       fir  <
zoo     zoo     for       for  <
                get       get  <
                gum       gum  <
                gym       gym  <
                hat       hat  <
                him       him  <
                hip       hip  <
                ill       ill  <
                ink       ink  <
                its       its  <
                zap       zap     zap
                zip       zip     zip
                zoo       zoo     zoo
-----|-------|---------|---------------
19   |  19   |  31     |  31
```

Here we have 2 files, with 31 lines each. Sort+uniq of the 2 files together also displays 31 lines, but diff displays 43 lines:

```
             | file1+2 |
             | sort    |  diff -y -W 12
file1| file2 | uniq    |  file1 file2
-----|-------|---------|---------------
act     act     act       act     act
all     all     all       all     all
and     and     and       and     and
bar     far     bar       bar  <
boy     fir     boy       boy  <
but     for     but       but  <
can     get     can       can  <
car     gum     car       car  <
cat     gym     cat       cat  <
dad     hat     dad       dad  <
day     him     day       day  <
did     hip     did       did  <
eat     how     eat       eat  <
eel     ill     eel       eel  <
egg     ink     egg       egg  <
far     its     far       far     far
fir     bar     fir       fir     fir
for     boy     for       for     for
get     but     get       get     get
gum     can     gum       gum     gum
gym     car     gym       gym     gym
hat     cat     hat       hat     hat
him     dad     him       him     him
hip     day     hip       hip     hip
how     did     how       how     how
ill     eat     ill       ill     ill
ink     eel     ink       ink     ink
its     egg     its       its     its
zap     zap     zap            >  bar
zip     zip     zip            >  boy
zoo     zoo     zoo            >  but
                               >  can
                               >  car
                               >  cat
                               >  dad
                               >  day
                               >  did
                               >  eat
                               >  eel
                               >  egg
                          zap     zap
                          zip     zip
                          zoo     zoo
-----|-------|---------|---------------
31   |  31   |  31     |  43
```

While this last example does not fit your specific case because one of the input files is not sorted, I have included it for others who may not have your exact situation.

Comment: Sorry for  a late response but thanks very much ! That helped !